# Need help can’t send Bitcoin

Tags: transactions

I purchased $40 worth of Bitcoin from a btc atm. I use this method to add to the same wallet every time a couple times a week. This time when it loaded to my wallet I needed to send it from there to another wallet on a site to use. It won’t send $32 saying I don’t have enough to cover the transaction fee. I look and see the transaction fee is $117.00??? When I’m sending $32 of btc? Why? [image]

Comment: Which wallet software is this? Good wallet software will allow you to specify the feerate you desire, though you do need to understand how transaction fees and the mempool (transaction queue) work in order to effectively manage your UTXOs.

Comment: My funds are on Coinbase wallet